# String - prefix negative sign

Tags: c#, string

Just came into trouble with this method. It's strange that if I pass any negative value with this method, it returns a negative sign after the `string` in `TextBox` output. I could not figure out why the negative sign is not showing in front of the `string`.

```
public string MakeCurrency(string variant)
{
    String _denom = "R 0.00";
    try
    {
        if (variant != "")
        {
            decimal _decimal = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(variant)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            if (_decimal >= 0)
                _denom = "R " + string.Format("{0:#,###0.00}", _decimal);
            else
                _denom = "-$ " + string.Format("{0:#,###0.00}", Math.Abs(_decimal));

        }
    }

    return _denom;
}
```

Comment: why do you keep the value as a `string`?

Comment: You are missing `catch` or `finally` block. Other parts of your code should work fine. There is no reason for negative sign to appear after number

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:#,###0.00}", Math.Abs(-12345.6789m)));` prints `12,345.68` as expected. The error must be elsewhere.

Comment: Tested your code and it shows the sign as a prefix... how do you bind it to your `TextBox`? Maybe the problem is there. By the way, you can format currency in an easier way if you want `string` -> `_denom.ToString("c")` Of course, the negative value will be displayed as a set of parentheses surrounding the value. You would have to provide `CurrencyNegativePattern` of `1` to change that behavior to a negative sign prefix.

Comment: string.format is affected b the current culture you have set. some culture setting can be overwritten to show negative at the end like my old ERP system. To enforce a format regardless of the current session culture you must use the following format method `Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and it is giving write answer, [Here](http://ideone.com/OoFGXH) I tested your code, and its working and giving correct output with negative values also (output with negative sign).

```
using System;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String outpt=MakeCurrency("-123456");
        Console.WriteLine(outpt);
            String outpt2=MakeCurrency("123456");
        Console.WriteLine(outpt2);
    }
    public static string MakeCurrency(string variant)
{
    String _denom = "R 0.00";

        if (variant != "")
        {
            decimal _decimal = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(variant)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            if (_decimal >= 0)
                _denom = "R " + string.Format("{0:#,###0.00}", _decimal);
            else
                _denom = "-$ " + string.Format("{0:#,###0.00}", Math.Abs(_decimal));

        }


    return _denom;
}
}
```